# Convert JSON to IMG type

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Is it possible to convert a JSON obj to an img, like gif or png? Basically, I want to take a screenshot of the returned JSON and turned into a gif or png type.

I've tried converting to the JSON to base64 but the image doesn't render. The base64 is returned correctly but it's not displaying.

index.html

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    const btn1 = document.getElementById('pressme');
    btn1.addEventListener('click', getData);
    function getData(e) {
        var id = document.getElementById("userid").value;
        $.ajax({
            url: `/${id}`,
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("data", data);
                $("#userid").attr("src", `data:image/png;base64, ${data}`);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log('Failed');
            }
        })
    }
</script>

<div id="main"><img id="id" src="" /></div>
```

server.js

```
app.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
try {
    const { id } = req.params
    const apiResponse = await fetch(
        'https://dummydata.com/' + id
    )
    const apiResponseJson = await apiResponse.json()

    let objJsonStr = JSON.stringify(apiResponseJson.results[0]);
    let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(objJsonStr).toString("base64");

    res.send(objJsonB64)

} catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.status(500).send('Something went wrong')
}
```

})

Comment: Hard to tell without the sample data, but it looks like you are stringifying json, then creating a buffer from that. Why not create a buffer from parsed json result? e.g., `let objJsonB64 = Buffer.from(apiResponseJson.results[0]).toString("base64");`

Comment: You are trying to generate an image containing human-readable JSON text characters? Or....? All you're currently doing is putting the base64 text there and claiming it is a PNG (which it is not).

Comment: You could write it into a `<canvas>` and convert to image using `canvas.toDataURL()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I Used This Approach:

```js
var imgElem = document.getElementById('img');
$('#urlText').keyup(function(){
   $('#img').attr('src',$('#urlText').val());
});
   
$('#sendData').click(function(){
var imgData = JSON.stringify(getBase64Image(imgElem));
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://url.com/rest/api',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: imgData,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
  });
});

function getBase64Image(imgElem) {
// imgElem must be on the same server otherwise a cross-origin error will be thrown "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElem.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = imgElem.clientHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElem, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
}
```